# Dockerizing Multi-maven project with docker-compose.yml

Tags: maven

I have a problem with a docker-compose on my maven-multi project.
My module won't start up on docker and the container throws an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

my parent pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>derived-markets</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.example.com</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.12</lombok.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring-boot.repackage.skip>true</spring-boot.repackage.skip>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>model</module>
        <module>saver-module</module>
        <module>testing-tool-module</module>
    </modules>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>8.0.23</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.3</version>
            </dependency>


        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

this is my module pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.example.com</groupId>
        <artifactId>derived-markets</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>saver-module</artifactId>
    <name>saver-module</name>
    <description>Database saver</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.23</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupIdorg.example.com</groupId>
            <artifactId>model</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>org.example.com.SaverModuleApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <finalName>saver-module</finalName>

    </build>

</project>
```

my docker-compose.yml is like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  saver:
    build:
      context: ./saver-module
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"
```

and actually its dockerfile inside the module:

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim AS build
ADD src /derived2/saver-module/src
ADD pom.xml /derived2/saver-module
RUN mvn -f /derived2/saver-module/pom.xml clean install

FROM openjdk:latest
ADD target/saver-module.jar /saver-module.jar
EXPOSE 8090
CMD ["java", "-jar", "saver-module.jar"]
```

Comment: What comes after `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:`?

Comment: ` Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication

at org.example.com.SaverModuleApplication.main(SaverModuleApplication.java:14)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication

at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)

at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)

at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)

... 1 more `

Comment: it says the same also if i run it from the project structure .jar with right click and "run ...jar"

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

Do not include  in your child POMs beacuause it will not generate a runnable .jars ...